# Set limit on Mysql general log in RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I have just enabled general log in my RDS parameter group.
However the log is growing in size like crazy. How do I set a limit on it?

[image: You can see the size of the log file here]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html#USER_LogAccess.MySQL.Generallog) you have a few options.

One thing to keep in mind is that the log files will never grow larger than 2% of the allocated storage.

According to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html#USER_LogAccess.MySQL.LogFileSize)

> The MySQL slow query log, error log, and the general log file sizes are constrained to no more than 2 percent of the allocated storage space for a DB instance

The behavior depends on the `log_output` parameter, which by default is `TABLE`.

You could update the `log_output` value to `FILE` to force log rotation every 1 hour, but be sure to understand the [differences](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html#USER_LogAccess.MySQL.Generallog) between these parameter values

Comment: well looks like there's no option to limit the size. Whatever you've mentioned are all I found as well. Upvoted for summary.